# fixed div inside section of fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I have a three section of my page that are inside fullpagejs. The middle page needs to contain a very tall div that is split in two columns. The left is the div that needs to follow right text that takes the entire height of div. But because the way the fullpage.js works(translate with css not actual scrolling i can't make div that is positioned fixed to behave like it should

HTML

```
<div class="section section-1 show-for-large">
    section1 content
</div>
<div class="section section-2">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 column"> 
        <div class="row" id="pokemon">
            <div class="small-5 medium-5 columns">
                <img src="/"> 
            </div>
            <div class="small-7 medium-7 column">
                <span class="title">
                    title
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row hide-for-large">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <p>
                  text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-5 column">
        <div>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="section section-3">
    section3 content
</div>
<div class="section section-4 fp-auto-height">
    section4 content
</div>
```

FULLPAGE JS

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionSelector: '.section',
    scrollOverflow: true,
    verticalCentered: false,
    normalScrollElements:'#pokemon',
    css3: true,
    });
```

I tried using plugins like http://stickyjs.com/ , and similar like it but the problem is they all work on principle of scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` instead of fixed. Then use `position:relative` for the section elements, so the absolute position will be related to the section.